# Selected item in a listview doesn't unselect

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, selection

I can select multiple items in a listview. But if i click on one, it turns blue. That's normal, so that shows it is selected. But if i click again on the same item, it doesnt uncheck. So i can't change my selection. Somebody who knows how to fix this stupid little problem?

Edit: This is my listview:

```
 <ListView Height="155" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedQuestionDropList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" dd:DragDrop.IsDragSource="True" 
  dd:DragDrop.IsDropTarget="True" SelectionMode="Multiple" Margin="0,0,542,436" Background="#CDC5CBC5"
                 dd:DragDrop.DropHandler="{Binding}" Name="DropListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SelectedExaminationQuestions,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged_1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Verkorte naam" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ShortName}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Omschrijving" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Description}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Type}" />

                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: I can work in codebehind, with OnSelectionChanged, if selected=true... but that looks some strange to me.. I hope there is a nicer way, just a property or something

Answer (score 6):

I was facing a similar problem and found that, while left-click always select the item pointed to, you can use Ctrl + left-click to toggle selection in a list view. This is the default behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a wpf behaviour. Something like:

```
public class ListViewBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Enfoca automaticament el item sel·leccionat
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoUnselectItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "AutoUnselect",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(ListViewBehaviour),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnAutoUnselectItemChanged));

    public static bool GetAutoUnselectItem(ListView listBox)
    {
        return (bool)listBox.GetValue(AutoUnselectItemProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAutoUnselectItem(ListView listBox, bool value)
    {
        listBox.SetValue(AutoUnselectItemProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnAutoUnselectItemChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listView = source as ListView;
        if (listView == null)
            return;

        if (e.NewValue is bool == false)
            listView.SelectionChanged -= OnSelectionChanged;
        else
            listView.SelectionChanged += OnSelectionChanged;
    }

    private static void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO write custom selection behaviour
    }
}
```

And to apply it to a listview:

```
<ListView bb:ListViewBehaviour.AutoUnselect="True">
    ...
</ListView>
```